# Javascript Validation Function

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a school assignment where I'm designing a web page to include form entry.  One of the parameters of the assignment is to validate a field where a user enters a name.(must be non-blank, must begin with a capital letter, and must contain at least one vowel and one consonant). As I'm learning the HTML part and not the JavaScript part, I'm allowed to use anything I find for the JavaScript so long as I cite the source.  Can anyone help with this?  I'm vaguely familiar with it but not nearly enough to "get it" on my own.  To be clear, I am not seeking assistance with html, only the JavaScript function that meets the name parameter:

(must be non-blank, must begin with a capital letter, and must contain at least one vowel and one consonant)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: SO is not meant to get your homework done by someone else. Post the code you've already tried to use and ask a specific question about your problem.

Comment: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp). That should get you started.

Comment: My point is that the JavaScript is not my homework, only something I've been told I could access online but can't seem to find.  My homework is implementing it into my html page and making it work.  I am allowed to copy/paste any JavaScript I find to make this work as long as I cite the source.

Comment: This is my code for the html, which is all I really have to add.  I just need the JavaScript for the function validateRealname()

tr>
                        <td><label for="realname">Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input id="realname" align="left" size="50" name="realname"
                                   onchange="validateRealname(this, 'realnameguide');"></input></td>
                        <td id="realnameguide">Please use proper case when entering your name.</td>
                    </tr>

Comment: @user3533863 - No need for JavaScript if you are just doing simple validation: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/#toc-validation

Comment: `Element.value` gets an input value. You can get an Element a number of ways. The most common is probably `document.getElementById('putIdHere')`. You can assign nearly anything to a variable: `var anyName = document.getElementById('putIdHere'); console.log(anyName.value);`. That would put the value, which is an HTML attribute, from the same Element with the `id='putIdHere'` into your Firebug Console. There are, of course, a number of way to get Elements. Since, `anyName.value` is a String you can run `anyName.value.match()`. Put a RegExp in `.match()`. You really just have to learn JavaScript.

Comment: agreed, however the idea of the assignment is to learn how to implement JavaScript into the html code.  That part I've learned, if only I had the correct script to meet the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, will return true if validation succeeds:

```
function validateName(name) { 
    var cap = /^[A-Z]{1}.+$/;
    var con = /[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/i;
    var vow = /[aeiou]/i;
    if(cap.test(name) && con.test(name) && vow.test(name)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.  I sincerely appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5 there is no need for JavaScript:

```
<input required pattern="[A-Z](.*[aeiou].*[^aeiou].*|.*[^aeiou].*[aeiou].*)">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sfjT9/

If you need to check validity in JavaScript, use this:

```
yourInput.checkValidity();
```

W3C specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-cva-checkvalidity
WHATWG specification: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-constraint-validation-api:dom-cva-checkvalidity

Comment: Yes, it's also not backward compatible.

Comment: @PHPglue - The question tagged HTML5 and it's okay to assume OP does not need backward compatibility.